# CORS Blocked when trying to access from local network

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cors

I'm making a webapp where the backend gets some data from a MongoDB and then the frontend displays it. Here's a simplified version of it:

- Backend(ExpressJs)

```
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;

app.use(express.json());

// Enable CORS for all routes
app.use(cors({ origin: '*'}));

/* 
 * ...
 * fetch data from MongoDB 
 * ...
 */

app.get('/api/data', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const data = await fetchData();
    res.json(data);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
  }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

- Frontend (ReactJs)

```
const App: React.FC = () => {

    const fetchData = async () => {
        try {
          const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3001/api/data') // Fetch data from server endpoint
          const newData = response.data
          // more code...
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error fetching data:', error)
        }
    };

    return //display data
}

export default App
```

When I run it on my PC (either directly from VS Code or dockerize them and as containers) it works fine, meaning that opening a borwser and going to `http://localhost:3000` shows the frontend page correctly with the data correctly fetched from the backend.

But when I try to access it from another device on the same local network, meaning opening the browser on another computer and going to `http://<ip_of_server>:3000`, the frontpage still loads, but the data is not displayed. If I look at the console it shows the following error:

```
Cross-origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:3001/api/data
```

(Also, if I go directly to the api endpoint (`http://<ip_of_server>:3001/api/data`) from the browser, it returns the raw data without issue)

What is the issue here? Do I need to configure something else on the CORS settings? Do I need to change something else?

Comment: React apps run in the browser. If it tries to make a request to `localhost`, that will be to the machine running the browser. You simply need to change the URL used in the `fetch()` request to the correct host

Answer (score -1):

The issue you are facing is due to the Same-Origin Policy (SOP) restrictions imposed by web browsers.

I would recommend you to try these two solutions :

1. Set server's IP address in frontend code. Since backend server is started in your local machine and you are trying to access to using localhost of another device.
2. Set headers

**1st solution :**

You've correctly configured CORS on your backend for allowing all origins using app.use(cors({ origin: '*' })). However, the problem is that you are trying to fetch data from the backend using the localhost address (http://localhost:3001/api/data) from the frontend server.

To fix this issue and make it work from other devices on the same local network, you should modify your frontend code to use the server's IP address or hostname instead of localhost. You can dynamically determine the origin at runtime based on the device's IP address or hostname.

Here's an example of how you can modify your frontend code to achieve this:

```
const response = await axios.get(`http://${serverIP}:3001/api/data`);
```

**2nd solution:**

```
  app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});
```

Here is a short and clear article that explains everything:

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/access-control-allow-origin-header-explained/

Some other sources to know about CORS error:

https://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html

https://williambert.online/2013/06/allow-cors-with-localhost-in-chrome/

Comment: OP is using the `cors()` middleware which is **much** better than writing your own CORS headers

Comment: The error encountered might persist even if you've correctly implemented the `cors()` middleware. This could be happening because someone is trying to access your backend from a different machine, using "losthost" as the hostname. Please let me know if my understanding is correct.

Comment: I'm referring specifically to the "2nd solution" part of your answer